# Falcon 9 fairings stability on reentry

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, reuse, recovery, fairings

On the descent of the fairings into the atmosphere how is stability provided?

Why does it not start to rotate in a uncontrollable fall but reenter gently without apparently damage on the interior side?

Answer (score 8):

> Q: "On the descent of the [fairings](http://www.spacex.com/news/2013/04/12/fairing) into the atmosphere how the stability is provided? Does not start to rotate in a uncontrollable fall but reentry gently without apparently damages on the interior side.".

Source [Elon Musk InstaGram](https://www.instagram.com/p/BfgHKDNAplx/):

> A: "It has onboard thrusters and a guidance system to bring it through the atmosphere intact, then releases a parafoil and our ship, named Mr. Steven, with basically a giant catcher’s mitt welded on, tries to catch it.".

Inside view:

[image: Nosecone (fairing) inside view]

The "catcher's mitt" ship Mr. Steven:

[image: Mr. Steven]

Like peanut butter on toast, it lands heavy side down; and [not where you want it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sod%27s_law):

[image: Fairing at sea]

Comment: That is a great answer, and good jokes, completely in context!  +1

Comment: @geoffc - Thanks, but there's better jokes here: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/24217/has-any-payload-been-as-silly-as-the-falcon-heavys-tesla-roadster/24220#24220

Comment: @Rob I'm all for foodthroporphizing spacecraft and their components; [If not constrained by underpasses, etc., would Falcon 9 have been less of a flying noodle?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21669/12102)

Comment: @Rob interesting photo of the fairing in the water. Was that still reuseable?

Comment: @Slarty - AFAIK it landed that way and was recovered floating, so stuff inside would be OK but the outside might not meet some Standards after contacting sea water.

Comment: Possible question: could simple elevons be used before parachute deployment, sharing the chutes steering actuators?