# Why are there advertisements in the Russian ISS flight control room?

Tags: iss, russia, flight-control, mission-control, roscosmos

I found a photograph of the Russian ISS flight control room:

[image: Russian ISS flight control room]
<sub>Source: NASA https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Russian_ISS_Flight_Control_Room.jpg</sub>

Below the large screen are several advertisements for companies. For example, Fortis (watches), HP, Omega, etc.

- Why is there advertising in a control room?
- What did the companies have to do to put their advertisement there? (e.g. sponsor equipment, or pay a fixed advertising fee?)
- Is this common practice in Russia or in any other country?

Comment: NASA director Jim Bridenstine touches a bit on some barriers between NASA and commercial advertising in [Bridenstine Speaks at NASA Advisory Council Meeting](https://youtu.be/dxV-v_YaboQ?t=1742) after about `29:02` (found [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32032/12102)). Only after NASA [astronaut Scott Kelley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Kelly_(astronaut)) retired could he freely [tweet about some of his favorites in his personal watch collection](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30763/12102). It could be that barriers are less rigid there.

Comment: In [that same video after about `31:54`](https://youtu.be/dxV-v_YaboQ?t=1914) Maxar Technologies [VP for Vice President for Regulatory / Policy Michael Gold](https://www.nasa.gov/offices/nac/members/MichaelGold-bio) goes into greater detail. See also Parabolic Arc's [NASA Examining Commercial Endorsements, Rocket Naming Rights](http://www.parabolicarc.com/2018/08/31/nasa-examining-commercial-endorsements-rocket-naming-rights/). These answer the question *Why aren't there advertisements in the American ISS flight control room?* but don't answer your question.

Comment: The resistance to mixing space and commercial ventures is so strong that we've essentially never seen an advertisement in the sky from Space, or (at least an overt) advertisement *in Space*. I'm not sure if Kubrick include any advertisements in his visionary extrapolation of what spaceflight would be like in this century in the 1968 film *2001: A Space Odyssey*. The question I linked above received [seven down votes along with seven up votes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOmRp.png) possibly because some people reacted negatively to the association of an advertisement with spaceflight.

Comment: [Did 2001: A Space Odyssey make any reference to the names of companies, or show any evidence of the existence of advertisements?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/224038/51174)

Comment: @uhoh I was wondering, can this be treated as advertisement in space: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:STS-41-B_EVA.jpg

Comment: @LeoS Wow, I think that deserves a question post of its own! "How often..." or "How many..." or "What were the rules..." or even "How did they get away with..."

Comment: They need the money.

Comment: There were several ads filmed on Mir. They needed the money. One was even done during an EVA. https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/19611/was-a-commercial-ad-balloon-satellite-ever-deployed

Comment: Bottom line, this is not new.  They need the money. "The resistance to mixing space and commercial ventures is so strong that we've essentially never seen an advertisement in the sky from Space, or (at least an overt) advertisement in Space." is wrong

Comment: @LeoS it's extremely common for contractors to put labels on their space devices. Sure, it's a form of advertising for name recognition.

Comment: There was a Pizza Hut ad on a Proton. https://news.slashdot.org/story/99/10/01/1546255/pizza-hut-pays-25e6-for-rocket-advertising

Comment: Also the space Coke machine. https://space.stackexchange.com/a/10352/6944

Comment: ...and Hilton/Doubletree [cookies on the ISS](https://newsroom.hilton.com/doubletree/page/11899) (apparently also [cookiesinspace.com](http://cookiesinspace.com) -- some "scientific experiments" can provide a lot of good PR)

Comment: @uhoh I think there are still a few companies working on (low) orbital [cubesat billboards](https://www.popularmechanics.com/space/satellites/a25950681/startrocket-space-billboards/) -- *they* certainly seem to have no objection to mixing space and commercial ventures.  On the other hand, some folks on the ground DO seem to object to the notion of having giant glowing Pepsi/KFC ads in the night sky.

Comment: The history of this issue can be found in the 1998 publication in Russian) https://www.kommersant.ru/doc/205035 
"On November 20, the Russian Space Agency intended to organize a direct advertising and commercial broadcast of the launch of the first element of the ISS - the Zarya module. However, NASA officials said: space should be ad-free."

Answer (score 6):

They needed the money.

> Sometimes it seemed the Russian space program would do almost anything
>   to raise money.....

(the book goes on to describe renting out the TsUP's lobby to a Czech lighting-fixture company, flying a Japanese journalist to Mir for cash, charging fees for interviews with program management, etc)

> The Russians were especially adept at working with Western
>   advertisers.  Down in the TsUP's main control room, an auditorium
>   where Russian ground controllers hunched over four parallel rows of
>   consoles beneath an overhanging mezzanine for observers, a large
>   Hewlett-Packard advertisement sat beneath the main viewing screen....

(the book then describes the Pepsi ad deployed from Mir and the abortive attempt to film a romantic comedy aboard Mir)

> As 1997 dawned, the program was barely alive. Funding snafus were
>   cancelling or delaying almost every major Russian space launch. Every
>   cosmonaut crew that made it to Mir could count on having its mission
>   extended; this way, the program saved money on rockets...

Source: The 1998 Bryan Burrough book *Dragonfly*, pp. 61-63

TsUP is a transliteration of the Russian acronym ЦУП which stands for Центр управления полётами 
"Flight Control Center"

Comment: And if anyone was wondering, TsUP is pronounced "tsoop", like in "soup".

Comment: I'm not sure if there's anything helpful here; https://youtu.be/6zFAme3SQAo